# plot matrix with lines gnuplot

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

I'm making a chart but I would like to use lines rather than points.

Using the style of lines, all the points are connected and the graph has a network appearance, which I don't want.

```
set grid 
set ticslevel 0.1 
set samples 51, 51 
set isosamples 20, 20 
set border 1+2+4+8
unset key
splot 'matrix.dat' matrix
```

## part of data to matrix plot

```
0.261   0.665   0.225   0.382   0.255   0.574   0.356
0.338   0.845   0.0363  0.167   0.727   0.0805  0.764
0.225   0.196   0.107   0.153   0.347   0.338   0.168
0.157   0.443   0.0671  0.135   0.312   0.408   0.362
0.151   0.281   0.0572  0.103   0.309   0.49    0.242
0.12    0.336   0.0604  0.173   0.19    0.395   0.153
0.119   0.173   0.0336  0.145   0.156   0.219   0.177
0.123   0.0452  0.0165  0.149   0.0932  0.0663  0.133
0.123   0.0741  0.00373 0.136   0.0346  0.485   0.131
0.111   0.241   0.0124  0.105   0.0127  1.01    0.122
0.096   0.475   0.0194  0.0569  0.0284  1.67    0.102
0.0777  0.773   0.0175  0.00929 0.0375  2.42    0.0831
0.059   1.11    0.0123  0.0322  0.0408  3.23    0.0635
0.0438  1.48    6.44E-4 0.0659  0.0265  4.07    0.0445
0.0349  1.92    0.0192  0.078   0.00585 4.92    0.0254
0.0392  2.42    0.0446  0.0632  0.0306  5.73    0.00774
0.0518  2.97    0.0745  0.031   0.0729  6.46    0.00716
```

[image: Model Graphics]

Comment: what exact plot command are you using? what code have you written? do you want a line plot instead of points?

Comment: @Zahaib I believe that the OP would like to use lines but when he does so, they are all joined together. If that is the case, the solution would be to put blank lines between the series in the input file. I agree, some code and some sample data would be useful.

Comment: @TomFenech, indeed, that seemed to be my first impression as well, but  hard to give any concrete suggestions without looking at the code and data file. Also to make it more useful for somebody later.

Comment: I used splot 'matrix.dat' matrix @ZahaibAkhtar

Comment: I agree with you but the matrix is only a fraction would have thought much points. If you need I'll be sending the attachment.- @TomFenech

Comment: It would be a lot better if you could provide a reduced, representative sample of your data and add it the question, as well as the code that you are using to plot the data.

Comment: I edit post with data. @TomFenech

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done automatically. You must determine the rows and columns of your matrix. First, to get the number of rows, use

```
stats 'matrix.dat' using 1 nooutput
rows = STATS_records
```

For the number of columns, use then

```
stats 'matrix.dat' matrix nooutput
cols = STATS_records/rows
```

And now plot every line

```
unset key
splot for [i=0:cols-1] 'matrix.dat' matrix every ::i::i lt 1 with lines
```

Result (with 4.6.4) is:

[image]

Comment: Either the above, which is the cleanest solution, or you will have to specify each line with its x, y and z vectors and then use lines or linespoints to plot

Answer (score 0):

I think Christoph's solution is just what you need, but to make the point clear, by providing the matrix and using `splot matrix` alone will just generate a mesh.

So you will need to specify the lines with complete X, Y and Z vectors and then plot them using splot with lines/linespoints. I'm adding an example below in case it may be helpful for anyone else.

You arrange your data file as follows:

`10  1   0.261   2  0.665 3  0.225   4   0.382   5   0.255   6   0.574   7  0.356
20  1   0.338   2  0.845 3  0.0363  4   0.167   5   0.727   6   0.0805  7  0.764
30  1   0.225   2  0.196 3  0.107   4   0.153   5   0.347   6   0.338   7  0.168
40  1   0.157   2  0.443 3  0.0671  4   0.135   5   0.312   6   0.408   7  0.362`

And then plot as follows:

```
set grid 
set ticslevel 0.1 
#set samples 51, 51 
#set isosamples 20, 20 
#set border 1+2+4+8
unset key
splot 'matrix.dat' using 1:2:3 with linespoints, \
'matrix.dat'  using 1:4:5 with linespoints, \
'matrix.dat'  using 1:6:7 with linespoints, \
'matrix.dat'  using 1:8:9 with linespoints, \
'matrix.dat'  using 1:10:11 with linespoints, \
'matrix.dat'  using 1:12:13 with linespoints, \
'matrix.dat'  using 1:14:15 with linespoints
```

With the resultant plot

[image]