# Gnuplot: How to remove mesh line parallel to x axis in surface plot

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, geometry-surface

I am plotting a surface from a data file. I want to remove the mesh line parallel to x axis.

Here is my code:

```
set xlabel 'x';
set ylabel 'y';
splot "-" using 1:2:3 notitle w l;
1 1.0 0.998
1 2.0 0.998
1 3.0 0.998
1 4.0 0.998
1 5.0 0.997
1 6.0 0.997
1 7.0 0.997
1 8.0 0.997
1 9.0 0.997
1 10.0 0.997

2 1.0 0.998
2 2.0 0.997
2 3.0 0.996
2 4.0 0.995
2 5.0 0.995
2 6.0 0.995
2 7.0 0.995
2 8.0 0.994
2 9.0 0.989
2 10.0 0.987

3 1.0 0.997
3 2.0 0.997
3 3.0 0.997
3 4.0 0.997
3 5.0 0.997
3 6.0 0.997
3 7.0 0.996
3 8.0 0.996
3 9.0 0.995
3 10.0 0.994

4 1.0 0.997
4 2.0 0.996
4 3.0 0.993
4 4.0 0.99
4 5.0 0.986
4 6.0 0.982
4 7.0 0.977
4 8.0 0.974
4 9.0 0.966
4 10.0 0.959
e
```

This will produce:

[image]

What I need is:

[image]

The second figure is produced by adding a dummy data line:

```
2 11.0 0.987
```

However, I am plotting from load of data files. I can not modify each data file to add a dummy data line. Is it possible by not adding dummy data line to produce the second figure?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to replace every empty line with two empty lines. Then you have one data block for every x-value. And points in different blocks aren't connected with each other:

The file `data.txt` contains:

```
1 1.0 0.998
1 2.0 0.998
1 3.0 0.998
1 4.0 0.998
1 5.0 0.997
1 6.0 0.997
1 7.0 0.997
1 8.0 0.997
1 9.0 0.997
1 10.0 0.997

2 1.0 0.998
2 2.0 0.997
2 3.0 0.996
2 4.0 0.995
2 5.0 0.995
2 6.0 0.995
2 7.0 0.995
2 8.0 0.994
2 9.0 0.989
2 10.0 0.987

3 1.0 0.997
3 2.0 0.997
3 3.0 0.997
3 4.0 0.997
3 5.0 0.997
3 6.0 0.997
3 7.0 0.996
3 8.0 0.996
3 9.0 0.995
3 10.0 0.994

4 1.0 0.997
4 2.0 0.996
4 3.0 0.993
4 4.0 0.99
4 5.0 0.986
4 6.0 0.982
4 7.0 0.977
4 8.0 0.974
4 9.0 0.966
4 10.0 0.959
```

Now plot this with

```
splot '< sed "s/^$/\n/g" data.txt' w l
```

to get

[image]

If you cannot use `sed`, you must use an approach similar to the one shown in [plot matrix with lines gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23747977/2604213):

```
stats 'data.txt' nooutput
splot for [i=0:STATS_blank] 'data.txt' every :::i::i lt 1 w l
```